# Why is it so easy to marginalize a multivariate random distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions):

> To obtain the marginal distribution over a subset of multivariate
>   normal random variables, one only needs to drop the irrelevant
>   variables (the variables that one wants to marginalize out) from the
>   mean vector and the covariance matrix.

Is there any intuition of why this works out so well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should readily follow if you look at the expression for the moment generating function (M.G.F.) for a multivariate normal density. M.G.F. looks like:

$E_X(e^{t'X}) = e^{\mu't + 0.5t'\Sigma t}$ for any real $n$-vector $t$, where $X = (X_1, X_2,...,X_n)$ is multivariate normal $N_n(\mu,\Sigma)$ random variate [simple to derive this!]

You can see from the expression that the exponent $\mu't + 0.5t'\Sigma t$ is a scalar and moreover, if you want to find the M.G.F. of a $p$-subset ($p \ne 0$) of the random vector $X$, say, {${X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, ..., X_{i_p}}$}, where, {$i_1,i_2,..,i_p$} is a permutation of {$1,2,..,n$}, then you just need to plug in $t_j=0$ for $j$ $\epsilon$ {$1,2,..,n$}-{$i_1,i_2,..,i_p$} in the expression of M.G.F. The simplified form reduces to a known M.G.F. of a uni/multi-variate normal and that M.G.F. uniquely determines a distribution confirms the nice property of the marginal density of multivariate normal distribution.