# Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have a Gaussian Joint Density, what are the following corresponding densities?

Tags: probability, integration

The question states that

> Suppose that $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\sigma^2(1-p^2)}} \exp\left[\frac{-(x^2-2py+y^2)}{2\sigma^2(1-p^2)}\right]$$ what are the densities of $f(x|y)$ and $f(x)$

The current method (albiet, long and tedious) I took was approaching it by taking by definition. That is, we know that $$f(y|x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}$$ and that $$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y) dy.$$

However, I can't seem to find a good way to do the integration where it doesn't come out ugly and hairy. Intuitively, it doesn't seem simplistic. However, are there any other ways of approaching solving this problem?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605850/why-is-it-so-easy-to-marginalize-a-multivariate-random-distribution?rq=1

Comment: I don't quite understand that how that relates

Comment: If you write the distribution in its matrix form, that the first comment guide as to how to find the marginal.